# switch translation variable in quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, vue-i18n

To print translation data I am using default command `{{ $t('failed') }}`

I would like to change the variable `t` to some other variable `{{ $t_abc('failed') }}`

Is it doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **main.js** or in **boot/i18n.js**

```
 Vue.prototype.$t_abc = Vue.prototype.$t;
```

Comment: I don't have main.js in my version. I have quasar.config.js only

Comment: do you have a i18n js file in boot folder, can put it there